# TextView.setText() in adapter bug

Tags: android, if-statement, adapter

I have a custom adapter extended `ArrayAdapter`. This is my piece of code in the `getView` :

```
if(searchBy.equalsIgnoreCase("title") == true)
{
    holder.title.setText(currItem.getTitle());
}
else if(searchBy.equalsIgnoreCase("publisher") == true)
{
    holder.title.setText(currItem.getPublisher().getName());
}
```

The problem is in the **second** if. Everytime the code enter the second if, the textview's text become empty (no text at all).

I have debug and log my apps to make sure the code is going to the second if. Now, i tried something like this :

```
if(searchBy.equalsIgnoreCase("title") == true)
{
    holder.title.setText(currItem.getTitle());
}
else if(searchBy.equalsIgnoreCase("publisher") == true)
{
    holder.title.setText("TEST");
}
```

The "TEST" in the second if never showed, the textview is just showing an empty string like before.

Then, i tried to reverse both of the if :

```
if(searchBy.equalsIgnoreCase("title") == true)
{
    holder.title.setText(currItem.getPublisher().getName());
}
else if(searchBy.equalsIgnoreCase("publisher") == true)
{
    holder.title.setText(currItem.getTitle());
}
```

When the code `holder.title.setText(currItem.getTitle());` is called from the first if, its working perfectly. However, **when its called from the second if, the bug appeared**. The textview is just empty.

I never encountered something like this before and i have been working hours trying to solve this.

This is my full `getView` :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View row = convertView;
        LinearLayout categoryWrapper;
        Holder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);

            holder = new Holder();
            holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_result_item_title);
            holder.category = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_item_category);
            holder.line1 = (View) row.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_line_1);
            holder.line2 = (View) row.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_line_2);
            holder.line3 = (View) row.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_line_3);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
        }

        categoryWrapper = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_category_wrapper);
        final PurchasedItem currItem = getItem(position);

        if(isStore == true)
        {
            currCategory = currItem.getBook_types();
            prevItem = (position == 0) ? null : getItem(position-1).getBook_types();
        }
        else
        {
            currCategory = currItem.getCategory().getName();
            prevItem = (position == 0) ? null : getItem(position-1).getCategory().getName();
        }

        if(searchBy.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("title") == true)
        {
            Log.d("auto1", currItem.getTitle());
            holder.title.setText(currItem.getTitle());
            //text = currItem.getTitle();
            //holder.title.setText(currItem.getPublisher().getName());
            //holder.title.setText("asd");
        }
        else if(searchBy.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("publisher") == true)
        {
            Log.d("auto2", currItem.getPublisher().getName());
            holder.title.setText(currItem.getPublisher().getName());
            //text = currItem.getPublisher().getName();
            //holder.title.setText("asd");
        }
        /*else if(searchBy.equalsIgnoreCase("author") == true)
        {
            holder.title.setText(currItem.getAuthor_name());
            //text = currItem.getAuthor_name();
        }*/

        //holder.title.setText(currItem.getTitle());

        if(source != 2 && source != 3)
        {
            holder.category.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.category.setText((currCategory.equalsIgnoreCase("magazine"))?"Magazine":(currCategory.equalsIgnoreCase("newspaper"))?"Newspaper":(currCategory.equalsIgnoreCase("book"))?"Book":"Apps");

            if (position == 0) {
                categoryWrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else 
            {
                if (currCategory.equals(prevItem))
                    categoryWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else
                    categoryWrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            holder.category.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // atur line
        if (position < getCount()- 1)
            holder.line3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else
            holder.line3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent n = new Intent(getContext(), SearchActivity.class);
                n.putExtra("keyword", currItem.getTitle());
                n.putExtra("source", source);
                /*searchby selalu title, karena meskipun user search by publisher, hasil di
                library activity berfokus pada title*/
                n.putExtra("categoryKeyword", "title");
                n.putExtra("type", category);
                getContext().startActivity(n);
            }
        });

        return row;
    }
```

Please kindly help me.

Comment: If you put a Log.v(..) in the second `if`, does it get printed?

Comment: YES, its printed normally. This is very frustating..

Comment: @GopalRao sorry, what do you mean? I have debug it and the second if is true, which mean the code is getting called

Comment: @BlazeTama post `getView()` method implementation...

Comment: @GopalRao done...i posted the whole method

Comment: Clean your project and re build it

Comment: @AnchitMittal done, not working :(

Comment: @Kedarnath yes, this is indeed a strange problem. Sorry but i cant send the project, its my office's not mine

Comment: @BlazeTama That's ok, I thought it is might a demo project. Can you add the code of .xml file which contains `autocomplete_result_item_title` TextView.

Comment: set one else condition for default after if and else if and check again

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are comparing a String you should always use trim() method to avoid white spaces.

Try this,

```
if(searchBy.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("title") == true)
{
    holder.title.setText(currItem.getPublisher().getName());
}
else if(searchBy.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("publisher") == true)
{
    holder.title.setText(currItem.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: @user issue is not about white spaces. edit your answer or delete before some one down vote

Comment: @BlazeTama, Ok try this, after both if condition, write this line `holder.title.invalidate()` and see what happens

Comment: @user2060383 nothing happened, the bug is still there and the code seems working normally